# Why doesn't vue.js routing work on Android's chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, vue.js, vue-router

I am building a webapp with Vue.js, webkit, firebase, vuex and vuefire. In this app I am using guards in on my router file to redirect my users after successful user login with the Google Sign In.

I would be VERY thankful if someone who would type some better code that works to do the samething: check if user is logged and redirect according to that (maybe using a mixin on each component to check if user is logged?).

But for now I am using routing guards...
While all is working on a desktop version and on iPhone, if I try to use my Android 5.1.1 on a Galaxy 5 (this error is also happening in other Android versions and other devices) it doesn't work!
Question 1) Does it look like this an issue  worth raising? And if so should I raise it with Firebase or Vue?

In my login.vue component script I am importing firebase, defining the provider `var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();` and then using a method as stated bellow.

I am getting no errors from the code below:

```
googleSignUp: function(user) {                       
   firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function(user, result) {
     var token = result.credential.accessToken;
     var user = result.user;  
 }).catch(function(error) {
     var errorCode = error.code; if (errorCode != null) { toastr.error(errorCode)}
     var errorMessage = error.message; if (errorMessage != null) { toastr.error(errorMessage)}
     var errorEmail = error.email; if (errorEmail != null) { toastr.error( errorEmail)}
     var credential = error.credential; if (credential != null) { toastr.error(credential)}
     });
  },
```

When this method runs, the app redirects the user to Google's sign in form and when the user gets back to login.vue I am redirecting the user to another page hello.vue if the login is successful using the created hook:

```
created() {                   
        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(result => {
            var user = result.user; // I am getting the user auth data! 
            console.log(user); 
                if (user) {                                               
                toastr.success("You're in!") // This WORKS! 
                this.$router.replace('/hello') // This DOESN'T WORK ON ANDROIDS but works pretty much everywhere else!
                }
            }).catch(error => {
             var errorCode = error.code; if (errorCode != null) { toastr.error(errorCode); console.log("error in getredirect code"); }
             var errorMessage = error.message; if (errorMessage != null) {toastr.error(errorMessage); console.log("error in getredirect message");}
             var errorEmail = error.email; if (errorEmail != null) {toastr.error( errorEmail); console.log("error in getredirect email");}
             var credential = error.credential; if (credential != null) { toastr.error(credential); console.log("error in getredirect credential");}
        });
    }
```

None of the error cases above is being thrown.

On my router/index.js file I have the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import firebase from '../firebase-config';
import {store} from '../store/store.js';
import toastr from 'toastr'
import landing from '@/components/landing'
import hello from '@/components/hello'
import login from '@/components/login'

Vue.use(Router)
let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history'
  routes: [
   { path: '*', redirect: '/landing' },
   { path: '/', redirect: '/landing' },
   { path: '/landing', name: 'landing', component: landing },
   { path: '/login', name: 'login', component: login },
   { path: '/hello', name: 'hello', component: hello,
            meta: {
              requiresAuth: true
            }
   },
  ],
})


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('landing') // i think this is where the problem is...
  else next()
})

export default router
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
at Repo.js:510
at Object.t.exceptionGuard (util.js:536)
at e.callOnCompleteCallback (Repo.js:501)
at Repo.js:314
at PersistentConnection.js:402
at t.onDataMessage_ (PersistentConnection.js:435)
at e.onDataMessage_ (Connection.js:262)
at e.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (Connection.js:256)
at t.onMessage (Connection.js:157)
at t.appendFrame_ (WebSocketConnection.js:197)
```

Again, this is webapp/site behaving as expected in almost in every browser and device except on Androids. Is there any safer and more device/OS agnostic way to do this? Am I missing something?

You can test what I am describing on the build version: https://clipclop020.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied` isn't this a firebase error ?

Comment: Hey @Jacob. Yes. I believe it comes from the _meta: {requiresAuth: true}_ that I have set on my router/index.js file.